# Combine two rdd - pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark, rdd

I have two RDD like below

```
r1 = [(u'5971', u'COLOR > RED', 599),(u'5131', u'MEN > BOW TIES > ALL IN COLLECTION', 599)]  # id, category, price

r2 = [(u'5131', 1), (u'5971', 1), (u'8347', 1)] # id, quantity
```

I want result to be like below:

```
r3 = [(u'5131', ('MEN > BOW TIES > ALL IN COLLECTION',599)), (u'5971', ('COLOR > RED',599)]
```

I have tried below:

```
r3 = r1.join(r2)
```

But price was missing in resultant r3 rdd.

Answer (score 0):

```
r1 = [(u'5971', u'COLOR > RED', 599),(u'5131', u'MEN > BOW TIES > ALL IN COLLECTION', 599)]  # id, category, price

r2 = [(u'5131', 1), (u'5971', 1), (u'8347', 1)] # id, quantity

r1_modified = r1.map(lambda (l,m,n):(l,(m,n)))

r3 = r1_modified.join(r2).map(lambda (l,m,n):(l,m))
```